# Repeated elements with dynamic datas code optimize in angular7

Tags: angular7

I need to stop a one set of elements repeated in my angular 7 application.

That set of elements are working with dynamic data.

So I create that set of elements in one component.

But I can't call that component inside of that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for that

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor='let link of links'>
        <ng-container 
             *ngTemplateOutlet="simpleLink; context:{link:link}">
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #simpleLink let-link='link'>
    Simple : {{ link.name }}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor='let link of link.childLinks'>
            <ng-container 
                *ngTemplateOutlet="simpleLink; context:{link:link}">
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ng-template>
```