# Ng-template repeat it self

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have ngb-typeahed when a user clicks on the input it will display all the values to the user as dropdown .i want to customize the dropdown typically that dropdown is list.in that case ng-bootstrap documentation says we can use a custom template for the displaying a result.in there we have to use ng-template for that.but the problem is I have an array of an object inside every object contains one property which is again an array. in the results list, first, I need to display object name then object array values.

```
<div>
 <ng-template let-r="result" #rt>
        {{r.categoryName}}
        <li *ngFor="let item of r.subCategoriesList">
          {{item}}
         </li>
</ng-template>
<input formControlName="category" [ngbTypeahead]="search"[(ngModel)]="model"
 (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
 (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead" type="text"
  class="form-control chevron-sign" [resultTemplate]="rt" />
</div>
```

problem is when I render like this whole ng template repeat it self.you can see it in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7c4nf?file=app%2Ftypeahead-template.ts)
my end result should be something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is whole template repeat inside that template. It's my solution is [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <li style="color:green">{{r.categoryName}}</li>
    <li *ngFor="let item of r['subCategoriesList']">
        {{item}}
    </li> 
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rt; context: {result:r.repeatTemplate, term: 'kl'}">
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

[stackoverflow.com: Similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878988/repeated-elements-with-dynamic-datas-code-optimize-in-angular7#answer-55879005)

Comment: @NicoleZ It's useful for your requirement.?? If any other solution you have plz share with me.